# automatic updating using bat files

Tags: c++, batch-file, updating

I implement auto updating of my application. At the end of downloading installer I have to

1. close my application
2. execute installer with new release.

I try to do that using the following bat script:

```
sleep 5
"C:/DOCUME~1/.../.../Temp\my_app_installer.exe"
```

In my main program code I write:

```
ShellExecute(0, L"open", batScriptPath.utf16(), 0, 0, SW_HIDE);
closeApp();
```

But it doesn't work. sleep function is not invoked and installer is executed before closing application. It's not good. Could you say me how can I fix this bug or another method of updating application.

Thanks.

Comment: "sleep 5" is not recognized as a valid command on my Windows machine. Does "sleep 5" work for you from the command prompt?

Comment: This command work on my machine (win xp, 32 bit).

Comment: Just for debugging, try "notepad" instead of "sleep 5" and see if it launches notepad. If it does, then the problem is probably that your sleep.exe is not being found by the command interpreter.

(Note, sleep is not a standard Windows XP command. I tried on a Windows XP machine and confirmed this.)

Answer (score 2):

You can write your task in the installer itself, instead of doing it in a batch file. the installer may examine if there old-app-instance open, and while it's open he'll just trying to close it. After success - he'll start the real installation.